# Stabilizers/dampers for refractor telescope

Tags: refractor-telescope

I have a basic refractor telescope. It's pretty light and so it catches vibrations and they never really settle down. Can I attach some dampers on it to cushion these?

Answer (score 2):

It depend where vibration are. Often (if you have a good mount for the telescope) all the structure vibrate and there are some good anti-vibration feet that can be useful. If the tripod isn't the problem and the vibration are only near the telescope, probably the problem is the mount that is under-sized for you telescope. In this case the only good way is change the mount with a sturdier one.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the root cause, vibration damping pads may or may not help.
Some telescope vendors sell sets of three for $50 or so;
an Internet search also yields a few do-it-yourself recipes using silicone caulk, sorbothane insoles, etc.
[Other home remedies](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-equipment/tune-up-your-telescope/) are possible,
such as adding weight or shims to the mount, or hanging a chain from the optical tube assembly.